# PHP Convert XML to Json with some (duplicate) elements to a Json Array

Tags: php, json, xml, laravel, converters

My Api (laravel) use Json code. Now I also want to support xml. The Xml message must be converted to Json so it fits into the existing structure. But I can not match the XML to the desired Json format.

Example XML and Convert to Json:

```
        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <catalog>
       <book>
            <author>Jan</author>
            <title>Xml to Json Array</title>
            <pages>
                <page>
                    <nr>1</nr>
                    <title>Welcome to my book</title>
                    <pagereviews>
                        <pagereview>
                            <name>maikel</name>
                            <comment>very good</comment>
                        </pagereview>
                        <pagereview>
                            <name>John</name>
                            <comment>i like this page</comment>
                        </pagereview>                            
                    </pagereviews>
                </page>
                <page>
                    <nr>2</nr>
                    <title>more info</title>
                </page>  
                <page>
                    <nr>3</nr>
                    <title>lots of fun</title>
                </page>                              
            </pages>
       </book>
    </catalog>";

    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $jsonString = json_encode($xmlObject);

    return $jsonString;
```

In Json this results in:

```
{
"book": {
    "author": "Jan",
    "title": "Xml to Json Array",
    "pages": {
        "page": [
            {
                "nr": "1",
                "title": "Welcome to my book",
                "pagereviews": {
                    "pagereview": [
                        {
                            "name": "maikel",
                            "comment": "very good"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "comment": "i like this page"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "nr": "2",
                "title": "more info"
            },
            {
                "nr": "3",
                "title": "lots of fun"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I need it without tags Page and Pagereview. Like this.

```
{
   "book": {
      "author": "Jan",
      "title": "Xml to Json Array",
      "pages": [
         {
            "nr": "1",
            "title": "Welcome to my book",
            "pagereviews": [
               {
                  "name": "maikel",
                  "comment": "very good"
               },
               {
                  "name": "John",
                  "comment": "i like this page"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "nr": "2",
            "title": "more info"
         },
         {
            "nr": "3",
            "title": "lots of fun"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$jsonString = json_encode($xmlObject);

return $jsonString;

Comment: That simply converts one to another - keeping exact structure.  You need to change the structure, so you'll need to write the code to parse your data. Start there - then come back with specific issues you're having

Comment: What do you need - do you want to change the original XML or is that fixed?

Comment: I think, you can't change that while converting to json. But you can get array and remove undesired levels

Answer (score -1):

I made several packages that integrate with Laravel to simplify XML. You can check them out here:

- [Collection Xml](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/collection-xml) - Convert a collection into XML
- [Request Xml](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/request-xml) - Convert incoming XML and merge it into the Request object
- [Response Xml](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml) - Convert data into XML for a response
- [Xml To Array](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array) - Convert XML into an array

If your xml needs to differ in structure from json, what I would recommend you do is look into [Spatie's Fractal package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal). It will introduce transformers for your data. Then you can conditionally set transformers before using my packages to have the data coming out exactly as you want.

Comment: im not sure but it looks like the Request XML would satify the OP requirements would'nt it?

Comment: Generally, links to tools or libraries [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.